# How to link packages in react-native

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I am getting these errors while running my app.

```
bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module ` react-native-screens` from `node_modules/react-navigation-tabs/src/navigators/createBottomTabNavigator.js`
```

How to solve this error. I just reinstalled the node modules and again installed the modules. Can someone help?

Comment: run this command in your terminal `npm install react-native-screens`

Comment: @Parth it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as of react native >= 0.60 there is no need for manually linking

***so for your issue***

remove node_modules folder 
and then

```
npm install

npm install react-native-screens

or

yarn

yarn add react-native-screen
```

close the terminal

clean the project => `cd android` => `./gradlew clean`

**remove the old app
then re run**

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your react native version for >= 0.60.x just run :

```
npm install react-native-screens
```

and for <= 0.59.9 :

```
npm install react-native-screens
react-native link react-native-screens
```

Answer (score -1):

Run following commands

```
npm install react-native-screens
react-native link react-native-screens
```

Comment: You can run above command only when you have react native version <0.6 otherwise for  version > 0.6 it automatically links packages to module.